# How to Set Custom Keyboard as Default keyboard of devise in Android.

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am Working on Custom/soft Keyboard application  i want to use this keyboard as default keyboard and set auto completion as normal keyboard but not getting how to do this .

i need urgently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for Language & Input in Settings.

Comment: i had open Language & Input in Settings by using this Code  :- Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);  but here the name of my keybord is not comming so i can set this as default input keyboard.